# What is the past tense of "cheers"? (As in a toast)

Tags: past-tense

Example:

> They raised their glasses and cheersed.

However, most dictionaries say that "cheersed" isn't a word.

Just using the normal past tense for "cheer" would be "cheered", but that doesn't sound like a toast anymore.

Comment: *Toast* is the verb they did. *Cheers* is the word they uttered.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Isn't that an answer?  I'd vote for it it as an answer, sov sov sov!

Answer (score 4):

*Cheers* has no past tense because it is an interjection, not a verb. Accordingly, it also lacks a present tense: it is equally impossible to say *"They raise their glasses and cheers!" or "He raises his glass and cheerses!"

You can say

> They raised their glasses and said "cheers!"

Comment: It appears that "cheers" is used as a verb also in non-standard colloquial usage and [_Wiktionary_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cheers) includes "cheers" as a verb (along with the interjection) with the meaning "To say "cheers" as a toast." [_Urbandictionary_](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cheersed) has "cheersed" also. When I search "cheersed", it mainly appears in social media messages. We can blame it on the internet.

Comment: You can verb almost anything in English (noun, adjective, prepositions, even conjunctions), but that doesn't mean it's dictionary-standard or elegant.